# PHP print only some part of the string

Tags: php, string, substring, trim

I have few PHP strings ($url1, $url2, ..) as below:

```
$url1 = "http://build:f9280396f83a0@mobile.com:8080/job/new-ios-2.1/buildWithParameters";

$url2 = "http://build:f9280396f83a0@mobile.com:8080/job/new-android-8.2/buildWithParameters";
```

How do I get the substring after `/job/` and before `/buildWithParameters`? Here is the expected output for $url1:

`new-ios-2.1`

So far I have tried using `substr` function:

For example, `$url1 = substr($url, -10);`. I am not able to find the above desired job part by this approach. Is there a better way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Regex -> `preg_match('/(?:\/job\/)(.*)(?:\/buildWithParameters)/', $url1, $matches); echo $matches[1];`. It's rough, and there is no doubt, a better pattern, but I feel this is the way you should be going. [**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#smaJH7ay1)

Comment: You could explode it, https://eval.in/625391.. Note `$url` is not a variable you defined so `substr($url,` will always fail.

Comment: @Darren your regex is too wide it matches the whole string between the first occurrence of `/job/` to the last occurrence of `/buildWithParameters/` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB8yH7/1) for the correct way please check my answer below :)

Comment: @AhmadHajjar That's why I said there's a better pattern ;-) +1'd your answer

Comment: @chris85 the explode is not the most efficient way in terms of performance and code prettiness :D , regex is way faster and beautiful :) check this please [Performance Profiling](https://eval.in/625399)

Comment: My eyes are always on efficiency and performance which blinded me from the rest of your comment ... I am sorry man :D and thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: @AhmadHajjar As stated the OP **could**. The explode would be more robust as it doesn't rely on `job`, nor `buildWithParameters`. My comment also addresses why the `substr` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use explode function . 4th key's value will be as per your expectation

```
$url1 = "http://build:f9280396f83a0@mobile.com:8080/job/new-ios-2.1/buildWithParameters";
$urlarr=explode('/', $url1);
print_r($urlarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
  preg_match('/\/job\/([^\/]*)\/buildWithParameters/', $url1, $matches);
  print_r($matches[1]);
```

This will match the string between first occurrence of `/job/` and first occurence of `/buildWithParameters/`

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hK3zH9/1)